# Ajax functionality seems to fail when on adding a div tag to my .js.erb file

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, css, erb

I am doing some styling in my code where I want to display the time a message is posted on a groups forum in my app. Currently posting of every message in this forum works with AJAX functionality implemented via jQuery 1.4.

On including the div tag in my `post_message.js.erb` file, I find that the message doesn't post on the groups home page (the place where I have all the group specific discussions - a functionality similar to what one would get to see in FB groups).

The message gets saved in my DB and on refreshing the page I get to see the latest message posted.

The code in post_message.js.erb looks like this:

```
$("#new_post").before('<div id ="new_post"><%= escape_javascript(flash.delete(:notice)) %></div>');<!--TO-DO the flash messages aren't yet enabled/working-->
$("#latest_post").prepend("<%= @group_post.message %> by <%=  Investor.find(@group_post.post_by).first_name %>  <%=  distance_of_time_in_words(@group_post.created_at,Time.now) %> ago <br/><br/><hr/>");
$("#new_post")[0].reset();
```

The above code stops functioning properly when I change the second line to:-

```
$("#latest_post").prepend("<%= @group_post.message %> by <%=  Investor.find(@group_post.post_by).first_name %> <div class ="contentdispgrp"> <%=  distance_of_time_in_words(@group_post.created_at,Time.now) %> ago </div><br/><br/><hr/>");
```

The part of the code corresponding the above in `_common.html.erb` file (this is a partial view where I have all the html tags and id's which I am eventually using in my `.js.erb` file) looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr>

<%if @current_user.is_an_existing_member_of_group(@investor_group)%>
<%form_for  :group_post, @group_post, :url => {:action => :post_message, :id => params[:id]},:html => {:multipart => 'true', :id => 'new_post'} do |f| -%>
    Start Discussion:<br><%=f.text_field :message%>
   <!--<%=f.file_field :photo%> -->
   <%=submit_tag "Post"%></p>
  <%end%>

   <div id = "latest_post"> </div>


<%for a in @group_all_posts %>
<%= a.message %> by <%=  Investor.find(a.post_by).first_name %> <div class ="contentdispgrp" id="style_chck"> <%=  distance_of_time_in_words(a.created_at,Time.now) %> ago </div><br/><br/> <hr/>

        <%end%>


</tr>
<%end%>
</table>
```

My post_message method in my groups controller looks like this:

```
 def post_message 
      @investor_group = InvestorGroup.find(params[:id])
  

      unless @current_user.is_an_existing_member_of_group(@investor_group)
        flash[:notice] = "Please join this group to participate in discussions"
        redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @investor_group and return # try to find out what exactly does this command do with return stmnt
      else
        @group_post = GroupPost.new(params[:group_post])
      end
      #@group_post = GroupPost.new(params[:group_post])
     
      investor_id = session['investor_id']
      @group_post.investor_group_id = @investor_group.id
      @group_post.post_by = investor_id
      if @group_post.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfully created.'
       # redirect_to :action => :show, :id => params[:id] - removed after trying to implement ajax via jquery
      else
        flash[:notice] = 'Post was not successfully created.'
      end
      

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :action => "show", :id => params[:id]}
        format.js
      end
     
  end
```

How can I fix this without refreshing the page? What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

group.js file code:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","text/javascript")
        }
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new_post").submit(function(){
        $.post($(this).attr("action"),$(this).serialize(),null,"script");
        return false;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was fixed by removing the extra quotes(") made use while defining the class wrt the stylesheet, there were already a pair of quotes with the prepend method.. in `post_message.js.erb.`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by adding another  tag to the page surrounding the controls I wanted to conceal or reveal.

I could not get either a div's display:none to work programatically, or an asp:Panel to toggle its visibility.

ASP.NET was rendering the page, in paticular the parts of it I wanted to conceal or reveal, before AJAX was able to change the display parameters. UpdateMode="Always" signaled to AJAX update other parts, too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm your ajax is working?  I would have expected to see a ':remote => true' in your form tag.  If its not there I wouldn't think your format.js response would get called.

```
form_for  :group_post, @group_post, :remote=>true ...
```

I think that when you do a page refresh it isn't calling the js code it's just calling the format.html instead.  To check you could check your log or put a print statement in the format block and see if it gets printed.

```
format.js do
    puts "I am here"
end
```

Comment: Hi James.. AJAX iS working, got the bug fixed too. Yep no doubt on refreshing html is being rendered. Why do you feel that a ":remote => true" needs to be given?. The form doesn't seem to be clearing the text field via reset method though... I am not sure why.. . And yes the bug was fixed by removing the extra quotes(") made use while defining the class wrt the stylesheet... Any idea on how to fix the reset button thing?

Comment: @boddhisattva, sounds good glad you got it working.  About the render=>true part, this has me a little puzzled because I had thought that is what is used to tell the form to use unobtrusive javascript to control the submit behavior (async call).  If the current form_for renders the post_message.js.erb (format.js) then how would you render the format.html?  I could be wrong, but its my feeling that the reset() doesn't work because the js.erb isn't getting executed.  Putting an alert("123"); in the .js.erb file would test that.

Comment: Since the current submit method as per the submit_tag is overridden by the submit method belong to group.js( a file that I created to get ajax working for me.. (will update its contents in the question) ) format.js is called. Its only in cases where one might go wrong in their syntax to display values as in the code of files like post_message.js.erb that html would be rendered(This is completely based on what I have understood and observed, anyone one..kindly correct me if I am wrong). To implement ajax via jquery i used http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery. This might help you..

Comment: @boddhisattva, ok makes sense now! :) I had learned to use the :remote tag in the form_for and it should do something similar to what you did in the .js file.  As for the reset(), I tested it on my form too and I noticed that when the "value" tag is set in the input field the reset() doesn't work.  I had to edit the html to remove the value.

Comment: I actually posted this as another question on stackoverflow, I got an answer too.. Kindly have a look at:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028413/unable-to-clear-text-field-with-overridden-submit-method-used-for-ajax-implementa